# How to specify font properties using / convention?

Tags: css

I am trying to modify the following code from this [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/3979221/cb69c5e8ccf0745fff2c94b47b27b108931f1a15):

```
.ctrl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  font: 1.5em/1.13 Verdana, sans-serif;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

`1.5em` seems to refer to the font size and the `position`, `top`, and `left` attributes seem to center the item.

What does the `/1.13` refer to?

Comment: this is NOT an ie7 hack, its the shorthand method for font-size/line-height font-family

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/1.13` refers to the **line-height**.

This is how you specify `font` in order:

```
font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family
```

More on the line-height property: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height